# Convert PHP array

Tags: php, associative-array

I have php array like:

```
['AL'=>'Albania','AD'=>'Andorra','AT'=>'Austria']
```

And I need to convert it into

```
[[code=>'AL',country=>'Albania'],[code=>'AD',country=>'Andorra'],[code=>'AT',country=>'Austria']].
```

How to do this in php?

Comment: Use a loop over the original array, and build a new array with the structure you want

Comment: use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/it/control-structures.foreach.php) to loop the data.

Comment: IF you didn't already saw it, i would recommend you to take a tour trought  the site here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $arr = ['AL'=>'Albania','AD'=>'Andorra','AT'=>'Austria'];
    $result = array();

    foreach($arr as $k => $v)
        $result[] = array("code" => $k, "country" => $v);

    print_r($result);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [code] => AL [country] => Albania ) [1] => Array ( [code] => AD [country] => Andorra ) [2] => Array ( [code] => AT [country] => Austria ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

The PHP script and the output which you require shows that you have to use associative arrays. these array permits the use of named keys within an array. You may simply get the required output by using the following code:

```
<?php

    $a = ['AL'=>'Albania','AD'=>'Andorra','AT'=>'Austria'];//Associative Array Declaration
    $output = array();

    foreach($a as $w => $x)//For every value in $a, it will display code and the country
        $output[] = array("code" => $w, "country" => $x);

    print_r($output);//Displaying the array output

?>
```